# Reorder a dataframe based on a character vector in rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

If you want to change the order of a dataframe based on the order of a vector you can do so with the following command:

RepEx

```
# Generate dataframe
nm1 <- data.frame(group=c("Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Green"), value=c("Spain", "Italy", "Germany", "Japan"))
# Generate vector with countries
countries <- c("Italy", "Japan", "Germany", "Spain")
# Reorder dataframe based on vector
nm2 <- nm1 %>% slice(order(factor(nm1$value, levels=countries))
```

However, I'm trying to do this on Rshiny between a reactive value `colors()`, and a reactiveUpdate `input$levels`, but it doesn't work properly.

Basically what I do is create another reactive object inside which I perform the transformation.

```
    nm1 <- reactive({
      a <- colors()
      nm1 <- data.frame(group=input$levels, value=a)
      nm2 <- nm1 %>% slice(order(factor(nm1$group, levels = input$levels)))
      nm2
    })
```

This changes the order of nm1$group, but it doesn't automatically change the value of nm1$value, which is what I want.

Comment: Can you show full example for shiny to test it.

Comment: It seems strange to use `slice` instead of `arrange` to change the order of rows of a data frame. Is there a reason you're not using `nm2 <- nm1 %>% arrange(factor(group, levels = input$levels))`?

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas. I indeed tried to do it with arrange as well. But the result is the same